# Tab S7 FE tablet with external bluetooth keyboard can't write caret ^ instead it writes ˆ

Tags: samsung, bluetooth, keyboard, tablet, external-keyboard

I'm using my tablet Samsung S7 FE with external keyboard Samsung Trio 500. There is a problem with the caret symbol. I can use write `ˆ` but LaTeX cannot work with `ˆ`.

I tried installing Google Keyboard but no luck with that. I've read similar posts on the web but there is no improvement. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: By the way, there is no problem for me to use "^" with copy-paste method but in Overleaf, I cannot use "}" in text math-mode and I copy "}" to use it in all environments.

Comment: Please do not add additional info in comments. Just edit the question instead. Please also add the information about what keyboard language layout the bluetooth keyboard uses. Last but not least I don't understand your question. What do you mean that you can write the caret symbol but Latex can't use it?